# How to return multiple parameters using pipes in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I've recently started working with angular and i'm working on implementing pipes. I have implemented my own custom pipe in angular. But the problem here is I want not only the **"RtgSlName"** parameter to be returned, but a list of parameters to be filtered.

My console looks like this:
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwJVb.png)

Can I return all the parameters like **"C1100SlName, C1100SmeName, RtgSlName, RtgSmeName"** from the **values** in my pipe? **(P.S: Please look the Console log image for the details)**

My component.ts looks like this:

```js
import { CampaignService } from './../../../services/campaign.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})



export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  
  constructor(private campaignService : CampaignService) { }


  Time;
  campaigns;
  filter;
  show:boolean = false ;
  selectedOwner:string;
  

  ngOnInit(){

    setInterval(() => {  
      this.Time = Date.now()
    }, 1000);
   

    this.campaignService.CampaignsInfo()
    .subscribe(response=>{
      this.show = false;
      this.campaigns = response;
    });

  }

  filterByOwnr(val){
    if(val != null)
    {
      this.show=true;
      this.selectedOwner = val;
    }
    else
    {
      this.show=false;
    }
   
    this.filter = val;
    }
  
}
```

My pipe.ts file:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: any[], value: string): any[] {
 
    if (!values) {
        return [];
    }
    debugger;
    if (!value) {
  
        return values;
    }
    return values.filter(val =>{

      return val.RtgSlName.includes(value);
    });
  }
}
```

And my HTML page looks like this:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns?.result | filter : 'OWNERS' : filter;">
  <td style="max-width:280px">
    <p>{{campaign.CampaignName}}</p>
    <small>{{campaign.DepartmentName}}</small>
  </td>
  <td>
    <small class="text-info">Active</small>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>{{campaign.Dialed}} / <small>1500000</small></p>
    <div class="progress mt-2 w-75">
      <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%;" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary cursor" (click)="filterByOwnr(campaign.RtgSlName)"> {{ campaign.RtgSlName }} &nbsp; &nbsp; </span>
    <a (click)="filterByOwnr()" *ngIf=show style="position: relative;  left: -16px;   top: -1px;  color: #fff;  font-size: 8px; border: 1px solid #fff;     border-radius: 15px;     font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; "><i class="zmdi zmdi-close zmdi-hc-fw"></i> </a> &nbsp;
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary cursor" (click)="filterByOwnr(campaign.RtgSmeName)"> {{ campaign.RtgSmeName }} &nbsp; &nbsp; </span>
    <a (click)="filterByOwnr()" *ngIf=show style="position: relative;  left: -16px;   top: -1px;  color: #fff;  font-size: 8px; border: 1px solid #fff;     border-radius: 15px;     font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; "><i class="zmdi zmdi-close zmdi-hc-fw"></i> </a> <br>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary cursor" (click)="filterByOwnr(campaign.C1100SlName)"> {{ campaign.C1100SlName }} &nbsp; &nbsp; </span>
    <a (click)="filterByOwnr()" *ngIf=show style="position: relative;  left: -16px;   top: -1px;  color: #fff;  font-size: 8px; border: 1px solid #fff;     border-radius: 15px;     font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; "><i class="zmdi zmdi-close zmdi-hc-fw"></i> </a> &nbsp;
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary cursor" (click)="filterByOwnr(campaign.C1100SmeName)"> {{ campaign.C1100SmeName }} &nbsp; &nbsp; </span>
    <a (click)="filterByOwnr()" *ngIf=show style="position: relative;  left: -16px;   top: -1px;  color: #fff;  font-size: 8px; border: 1px solid #fff;     border-radius: 15px;     font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; "><i class="zmdi zmdi-close zmdi-hc-fw"></i> </a>

  </td>

  <td class="ml-0 pl-0">
    <a [routerLink]="['/campaign-details' , campaign.Id]" [queryParams]="{ CampaignName : campaign.CampaignName , SubCampaign : campaign.SubCampaign, DepartmentName : campaign.DepartmentName }"><img src="../../assets/Images/next.png" class="next" /></a>
  </td>

</tr>
```

Help is much appreciated. Much thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite follow you, you want to return a string?

Comment: Multiple returns will only be supported by an array/object, etc

Comment: @xyz sir, Can you please look my console log? If you still don't understand, I can explain.

Comment: I see, you return currently has an array of objects. Array length is 60, What response do you expect? keys of first Object in the array? I believe all the objects in the array will have the same keys

Comment: Share your `filterByOwnr` function.

Comment: @xyz sir, this is a releated thread to: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626484/binding-the-data-from-component-in-html-page-angular-6)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had over complicated your implementation. It should be pretty simple as -

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: any[], key: string, property:any, value: string): any[] {

    if (!value) {
      return values;
    }

    return values.filter(val => val[property] === value);
  }
}
```

Just set the `property` value as `C1100SlName or C1100SmeName or RtgSlName, RtgSmeName`.

> Note : You are not using `key` here. I am not sure but you might have kept it other purpose.

Comment: Sir, i not only need the **RtgSlName** but all the parameters such as **"C1100SlName, C1100SmeName, RtgSlName, RtgSmeName"**

Comment: It will return the array of entire object which will contains all properties  `C1100SlName, C1100SmeName, RtgSlName, RtgSmeName`

Comment: Sir, can you be more specific? Or can you edit your answer accordingly so that I can understand better. Much thanks for your help.

Comment: Updated the answer with additional property, now you can pass any property like  `C1100SlName, C1100SmeName, RtgSlName, RtgSmeName`

Comment: I'm modified the solution accordingly to work to my requirement. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using the includes() method in the wrong way. The definition of the method is:

> The includes() method determines whether an array contains a specified
>   element.
>
> This method returns true if the array contains the  element, and false
>   if not.

You are trying to check if a string contains a value using a method that is made to check arrays. 
Why don't you try to check if the value is a substring of the RtgSlName, like this:

```
if(val.RtgSlName.indexOf(value) >= 0){
      return val;
 }
```